# How to get datatype attribute in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose that I've this `<div>`:

```
<div id="input-containers">
   <div class="form-group" datatype="admins operators">
      <label for="first-name"> *</label>
      <input type="text" id="first-name" class="form-control required" />
   </div>

   <div class="form-group" datatype="admins operators">
      <label for="last-name"></label>
      <input type="text" id="last-name" class="form-control required" />
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I've two `<input>`s, what I need to do is get all the `<input>` to have `operators` as datatype, I did this:

```
$('#input-containers :input').each(function()
{
   console.log($(this).attr('datatype'));
});
```

but this returns `undefined`, why?

Comment: Because the input hasn't `datatype` attribute, div has it. Use `$('#input-containers [datatype]').each(...`

Comment: seems weird you are not using a data attribute.. aka `data-type`

Comment: @epascarello what does change?

Comment: makes it a valid attribute, allows you to use jQuery data() or DOMs dataList

Comment: @epascarello so if I change with `data-type` I can access through $(this).data('type')?

Comment: That would be correct.

Comment: @epascarello thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
$('#input-containers .form-group').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr('datatype'));
});
```

Or if you want to use your code, you should place the **datatype attribute** on the **input tag**.

Comment: You've shown a working approach, but you haven't answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up to parent `div` as `this` refers to `input` which doesn't the said attribute

```
$('#input-containers form-group[datatype] :input').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).closest('.form-group').attr('datatype'));
});
```

```js
$('#input-containers form-group[datatype] :input').each(function() {
 console.log($(this).closest('.form-group').attr('datatype'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input-containers">
  <div class="form-group" datatype="admins operators">
    <label for="first-name">*</label>
    <input type="text" id="first-name" class="form-control required" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" datatype="admins operators">
    <label for="last-name"></label>
    <input type="text" id="last-name" class="form-control required" />
  </div>
</div>
```

---

However I would recommend you to use `data-*` prefixed attribute

```
<div class="form-group" data-type="admins operators">
```

Then use

```
$('#input-containers  form-group[datatype] :input').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).closest('.form-group').attr('data-type'));
});
```

[`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) can also be used. However it should be used judiciously.

Comment: But your code select all inputs even those hasn't `datatype` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You should target the parent div having class name .form-group and get the attribute

check the below snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#input-containers :input').each(function()
  {
     console.log($(this).parent('.form-group').attr('datatype'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div id="input-containers">
   <div class="form-group" datatype="admins operators">
      <label for="first-name"> *</label>
      <input type="text" id="first-name" class="form-control required" />
   </div>

   <div class="form-group" datatype="admins operators">
      <label for="last-name"></label>
      <input type="text" id="last-name" class="form-control required" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it will also work,

**JS:**

```
$('#input-containers :input').each(function()
{
   console.log(this.parentElement.getAttribute('datatype'));
});
```